# Mysqli with unknown bind_results

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok, I thought I had this, but I can't see why it's not working...
I have a SELECT with a variable table, hence my columns (bind_result) is going to be variable.
I need to adjust for any number of columns coming back, and fetch as an associated array, since there will be multiple rows coming back:

```
// Get table data
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','login','passwd','db');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno()) { $errors .= "<br>Cannot connect: ".$mysqli->connect_error()); }
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $table);
$stmt->execute();

// Get bind result columns
$fields = array();
// Loop through columns, build bind results
for ($i=0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
$fields[$i] = ${'col'.$i};
}

// Bind Results
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_result'),$fields);

// Fetch Results
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $results[$i] = array();
  foreach($fields as $k => $v)
     $results[$i][$k] = $v;
  $i++;
}

// close statement
$stmt->close();
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated ^*_*^

EDIT: New code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host','login','passwd','db');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)) { $errors .= "<br>Cannot connect: ".$mysqli->connect_error()); }
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;

if ($query = $mysqli->query($stmt)) {
$results = array();
while ($result = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $result;
}
$query->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the endgame?

Comment: This is a detail page to display various tables in the database and their contents, for an easy backend to edit the DB.

Comment: Are you getting an error or just no output?

Comment: No, nothing! I wish I was getting an error; it just renders nothing, bank page.

Comment: I think it may be because you are saving your info into an array but not doing anything. Try doing this: `var_dump($results); die();`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to go through line by line, but I finally got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind the table name. Bind_param accept the column name and its datatype.

To use the table name dynamically use the below code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table);
```

Comment: So is everything else good then? I assume I still need to bind the results...?

Comment: @Kaceykaso no need to bind table name. if you are using the column name then you can bind the column name.

Comment: Ok, now I feel really lost. I edited the code to the above code, and its still not going through. I feel like that's almost word-for-word what they have [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)...

Comment: So I went through earlier today, and got it working. I think I just had too many different approaches all mixed up; once I cleaned it line by line, I got it :)